# Difference between NVL and OR in SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause

Hej guys, could someone explain to me difference between NVL() and OR in below query :

```
Select 
count(*)                         
from SHIPMENTSTATUS  
WHERE insert_date  between  trunc(sysdate) -2 and  trunc(sysdate) -1  or  update_date BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) -2 and  trunc(sysdate) -1
```

Number of rows: **44937**

and

```
Select 
count(*)
from SHIPMENTSTATUS  
where NVL(UPDATE_DATE, INSERT_DATE) between  trunc(sysdate) -2 and  trunc(sysdate) -1
```

Number of rows: **44782**

Why we have this difference: 155 rows? i built a few query based on nvl and notice that issue and going to switch to `OR`, but I really want to know, why it such a difference. Thank you for explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `UPDATE_DATE` is not null `NVL(UDATE_DATE, INSERT_DATE)` evalulates to `UPDATE_DATE` and `INSERT_DATE` will not be used at all. Records with `INSERT_DATE` in the range, but a non null `UPDATE_DATE` outside of that range will be included in the first query, but excluded in the second.

Answer (score 0):

The first conditional expression checks if either of the two columns is in the target date range.

The second expression checks the second column *only if* the first column is `null`. So if the first column is not `null` *and* not in the range, the condition is not fulfilled. This is more restrictive.

Something equivalent to:

```
nvl(update_date, insert_date) 
    between  trunc(sysdate) - 2 and  trunc(sysdate) - 1
```

Would be:

```
update_date between  trunc(sysdate) - 2 and trunc(sysdate) - 1  
or ( 
    update_date is null 
    and insert_dateBETWEEN trunc(sysdate) - 2 and  trunc(sysdate) - 1
)
```